# $\Bbb Z_2$ subgroup of $\operatorname{SO}(6)$.

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory

I have seen the following statement made regarding the $\Bbb Z_2$ as a subgroup of $\operatorname{SO}(6)$: Viewed as a subgroup of $\operatorname{SO}(6)$, the $\Bbb Z_2$ generators are

$\Bbb Z_2 = \operatorname{diag}\{-1,-1,-1,-1,1,1\}$

$\Bbb Z_2 =  \operatorname{diag}\{1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1\}$

I don't understand this, since, $\Bbb Z_2$  has 2 generators and in the 1D representation they are simply

$\Bbb Z_2 =\{-1,1\}$

What are these generators in the 6D picture (which one correspond to the identity 1, and which one correspond to the -1 element)?

Furthermore, how can one build a 6D representation of $\Bbb Z_2$  in $\operatorname{SO}(6)$ that look like those? Shouldn't they be simply

$\Bbb Z_2 =   \operatorname{diag}\{-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1\}$ and $\Bbb Z_2 =   \operatorname{diag}\{1,1,1,1,1,1\}$ ?

Comment: You notice that $diag\{-1,-1,-1,-1,1,1\}$ represents a diagonal matrix, whereas $\{-1,1\}$ represents the elements in your group, right ?

Comment: The two $6 \times 6$ diagonal matrices that you wrote down generate a group of order $4$ isomorphic to $Z_2 \times Z_2$.

Comment: Yes I am a bit confused, it's true that the 2 $6x6$ diagonal matrices that I wrote down generate $Z_2\times Z_2$, but I can't see what  the explicit 6$\times 6$ form of the 4 generators of this  $Z_2\times Z_2$ group are.

Comment: Part of your confusion is that you are referring to elements of groups as generators. $Z_2 \times Z_2$ can be generated by the two matrices that you wrote down. The other two elements in the group are the identity matrix and the element you get by multiplying the two generators, which is ${\rm diag}(-1,-1,1,1,-1,-1)$. You mean $Z_2$ has two elements, not two generators.

Comment: Thank you ! I got the part about 4 elements and 2 generators of $Z_2\times Z_2$ now. But it still isn't clear to me how to get this particular form in 6 dimensions (sorry for being so dense) or in D dimensions in general.  If we just talk about $Z_2\subset SO(6)$ and not $Z_2\times Z_2 \subset SO(6)$, is it true then that the 2 elements of $Z_2$ are $diag\{-1,..., -1\}$ and $diag\{1,...,1\}$?

Comment: No, any diagonal matrix with entries $\pm 1$ and determinant $1$ generates a subgroup isomorphic to $Z_2$.

Comment: Okay, so I guess my question would be: How do the 2 elements of $Z_2$ look like when one embeds $Z_2$ as a subgroup of a Lie group like $SO(D)$? What are the differences between the 2 elements of $Z_2\subset SO(6)$ and the 2 elements of $Z_2\subset SO(7)$, for example? I am new to group theory and I've browsed through some textbooks but there isn't much discussion on $Z_2\subset SO(D)$.

Answer (score 1):

*As @DerekHolt states in the  comments . . .*

Any diagonal matrix with entries from $\{-1,1\}$ and determinant $1$, excluding the identity, generates a subgroup of $\operatorname{SO}(6)$ isomorphic to $\Bbb Z_2$.

Comment: It's perhaps worth adding that there other elements of $SO(6)$ of order $2$ (and which hence generate a subgroup isomorphic to $\Bbb Z_2$), including the conjugates of those examples by arbitrary elements of $SO(6)$.